# Sitecore GlassMapper RenderImage with Lazy Loading

Tags: razor, sitecore

Please excuse my ignorance on this.

Right now, I'm rendering an image using the following code:

```
@RenderImage(Model, x => x.Image, new { @class = "card-image" }, isEditable:true)
```

I need to update that code to match the following format for lazy loading, while keeping the image editable.

```html
<img data-src="@image" alt="" class="card-image lazy">
<noscript><img src="@image" alt="" class="card-image"></noscript>
```

How would I go about setting up something like this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to check if the page is in Experience Editor mode and handle that code differently from what you need rendering on the client.

Sometimes the simple approach when trying to configure a page for Experience Editor is best way.

Example:

```
@if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor)
{
    @RenderImage(Model, x => x.Image, new { @class = "card-image" }, isEditable:true)
}
else
{
    if(Model.Image != null)
    {
        <img data-src="@Model.Image.Src" alt="" class="card-image lazy">
        <noscript><img src="@Model.Image.Src" alt="" class="card-image"></noscript>
    }       
}
```